# how to switch between activities in ItemClickListener?

Tags: android, android-activity

in my app I'm using four activities for showing date using listView.
I tried many things but I'm newbie in android .please help me to complete my first app.thanks for helping
here is my code. How to switch between activities?

```
resultListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id)
                    {



                            Intent j = new Intent(getBaseContext(), book_content.class);
                            String my_id1 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();

                            j.putExtra("id", my_id1);

                            startActivity(j);


                            Intent k = new Intent(getBaseContext(),book_content2.class);
                            String my_id2 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();

                            k.putExtra("id", my_id2);

                            startActivity(k);


                            Intent q = new Intent(getBaseContext(),book_content3.class);
                            String my_id3 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();

                            q.putExtra("id", my_id3);

                            startActivity(q);


                            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), book_content4.class);
                            String my_id4 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();

                            i.putExtra("id", my_id4);

                            startActivity(i);



                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: In which conditions, you want which activity to start? Your code is starting all 4 activities simultaneously. You need a switch or if case to check positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List `OnItemClick` gives position of row, if you map list position than you can navigate to other activities. just change it:

```
resultListView.setOnItemClickListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getBaseContext(), book_content.class);
                    String my_id1 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();
                    j.putExtra("id", my_id1);
                    startActivity(j);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent k = new Intent(getBaseContext(), book_content2.class);
                    String my_id2 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();
                    k.putExtra("id", my_id2);
                    startActivity(k);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent q = new Intent(getBaseContext(), book_content3.class);
                    String my_id3 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();
                    q.putExtra("id", my_id3);
                    startActivity(q);
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), book_content4.class);
                    String my_id4 = resultBooks.get(position).get("id").toString();
                    i.putExtra("id", my_id4);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                }
            })
        }
);
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: thanks but it's not work for me.i cant get position value

Comment: finally i fixed it